# How to deselect a line selected using right click in the primeng contextMenu?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, contextmenu, primeng

I have an Angular table and created a right-click popup menu using the contextMenu property.   When I right-click a line, it gets selected (highlighted in blue) and a little menu appears.

If I select an action of the menu everything works fine, but if I decide not to select anything and click anywhere else on the table the selected line remains blue.

Normally when I select a line with the left-click, I can simply unselect it with another left-click. But for the right click I can't manage getting rid of the selection.

Below is the related part of code.

Angular:

```
initializeContextualMenu() {
  this.menuTrackFields = this.getMenuTrackFields(); 
}

getMenuTrackFields() {
  return [
    {
      label: 'Delete',
      icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-trash',
      command: (event) => this.deleteField(this.selectedField)
    }
  ]   
}
```

HTML:

```
<p-contextMenu #sc [model]="menuTrackFields" ></p-contextMenu>
```

How to deselect the right-clicked line?

Comment: I have the same Problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: The same problem, did you solve?